# Unable to influence the web-browser control's rendering engine choice

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10

As far as I am aware, there are three techniques by which I can influence the way a given webpage is rendered in Internet Explorer (short of changing the code of the page):

- The document type declaration (`<!DOCTYPE>` tag).  This influences whether a page is rendered in Standards, Almost Standards, or Quirks mode.
- The `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag.  This will cause the browser to use a particular rendering engine (if possible).
- The `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` registry entry.  [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), how this setting impacts the way a page is rendered will sometimes be affected by the document type declaration. 
   (for a 32 bit program running on a 64 bit machine, the exact path of the registry entry is located under the wow6432node subtree)

I have a Silverlight application contained in a simple html page, both of which I control.  Within the Silverlight application I have access to the [BrowserInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.browserinformation%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class, through which I can access various details about the browser context that the app is running in.  These include:

- [BrowserVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.browserinformation.browserversion%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which corresponds to the JavaScript function `Navigator.appVersion`.
- [ProductVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.browserinformation.productversion%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which is extracted from `Navigator.userAgent`

Note: I have not verified that the number I get in SL is, in fact, the same as I would get if I called `Navigator.appVersion` from JavaScript.

At this point it would be simplest to outline the behaviors I am observing using a table. As far as I can tell, SO does not support tables in answers, so please bear with me.

On Windows 7 SP1 (64bit) with IE10 (10.0.9200.16866) installed, I arrange my test as follows:

FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"iexplore.exe"=dword:000022b8
```

(`dword:000022b8` is equivalent to a decimal value of 8888, as described in [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

(almost-standards)

X-UA META:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=IE8">
```

I assume IE10 will ignore the `chrome=IE8` portion of the meta tag but I include it here for completeness.  It also may be relevant to mention that the DOCTYPE is the first entry in the html file and the X-UA meta tag is the first element inside the head tag.

With this setup in place, I use my Silverlight app to look up the values for ProductVersion and BrowserVersion.  The results are 9.0 and 5.0, respectively.  Performing various other permutations of this test by removing different combinations of the three yields PV:9.0/BV:5.0 when X-UA meta tag is present and PV:8.0/BV:4.0 when x-UA is removed but the registry entry is present.  With only the DOCTYPE present, ProductVersion is 10.0 and BrowserVersion is 5.0.

These results appear reasonable to me, assuming that X-UA meta tag overriding the registry entry is expected behavior.  I have no reason to think otherwise.

Now, if I switch to hosting the Silverlight app in the .net web-browser control, I see very different results.

For this series of tests, I need to adjust the registry entries slightly as follows:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"iexplore.exe"=dword:000022b8
"foo.exe"=dword:000022b8
```

where `foo.exe` is the name of a simple WPF app that contains the web-browser control.

With this revised setup in place, the results are PV:7.0/BV:4.0, when the registry entries are not present, and PV:10.0/BV:5.0 when they are.  This appears to be regardless of any changes to the X-UA meta tag and also appears to completely ignore the actual value of the registry entry.

So, to summarize my questions:

1. Are there other things influencing the rendering that I am unaware of?
   (particularly in the web-browser control)
2. What's going on with the version numbers being reported by the web-browser control?
3. Are the version numbers actually indicative of the rendering engine being used?
   (based on my observations it would appear that the web-browser control is rendering in IE10 mode when PV reports 10.0)

Finally, this setup may seem a bit peculiar.  I could easily have performed the same tests via simpler means (without SL, for example).  Needless to say, there is more to this issue than I have described here.  Hopefully, the detail that I have removed is not actually pertinent to the odd web-browser control behavior I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2):

1. When you host the WebBrowser ActiveX control in an application it defaults to IE7 doc mode for compatibility. When IE8 shipped, most applications that hosted the control expected IE7 behaviour and would break if switched to IE8 doc mode. As you describe, you can change this default with the registry setting.
2. I'm not an expert with Silverlight but I imagine the ProductVersion is coming from the Mozilla/x.x part of the UA string. IE uses Mozilla/5.0 for all recent releases. Relying on ProductVersion and BrowserVersion is probably not a good idea these days given [the values we needed to set in IE for interop](http://aka.ms/ie11ua) with today's web content. [document.documentMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc196988) will tell you the doc mode more reliably.
3. I'm not sure what PV will report for IE11 - probably not 11. document.documentMode is probably better but does require you to retrieve this from the DOM.